# if staleTime is bigger than cacheTime in react query, what happen?

Tags: react-query

What happens if the staleTime is longer than cacheTime, such as when the staleTime is 10 minutes and the cacheTime is 5 minutes? I thought that even if cacheTime is not valid after 6 minutes, staleTime is still valid, so it doesn't call to server to get the data.

However, I found a post that says that if cacheTime is not valid, and the data -that still fresh- will be deleted. If staleTime is longer than cacheTime, doesn't staleTime work as I expected?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to make the stateTime longer than the cacheTime. Your data should become stale before it is removed from the cache.

Comment: @Chad S. Yes, I know. but i wonder how it works if that happen like setting the staleTime longer than the cacheTime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`staleTime` and `cacheTime` are two completely different times that are not related *at all*.  They serve two different purposes and can be two different times - each one can be smaller or larger than the other, it doesn't matter.

I'll copy the section from [my blogpost](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query) here:

> StaleTime: The duration until a query transitions from fresh to stale. As long as the query is fresh, data will always be read from the cache only - no network request will happen! If the query is stale (which per default is: instantly), you will still get data from the cache, but a background refetch can happen under certain conditions.

The first thing to notice here is that even if `staleTime` elapses, there will not be a request immediately. `staleTime` just says: Hey, the data that we have in the cache is no longer fresh, so we might refresh it in the background. But for a background refresh to happen, it needs a "trigger": A component mount, a window focus, a network reconnect.

> CacheTime: The duration until inactive queries will be removed from the cache. This defaults to 5 minutes. Queries transition to the inactive state as soon as there are no observers registered, so when all components which use that query have unmounted.

`cacheTime` does *nothing* as long as you use a query. You can open a webpage and work on that page for *forever*  - React Query will not remove that data, because that wold mean the screen would transition to a loading state. That would be bad. `cacheTime` is about gargabe collection - removing data that is no longer in use. This is why we'll rename this option to `gcTime` in the next major version.

---

From the comments:

> It doesn't make sense to make the stateTime longer than the cacheTime.

Yes, it does, if you want. You can even have `staleTime: Infinity`, `cacheTime: 0`. This basically means: Never refetch data if you have cached data, but remove data from the cache as soon as I don't use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked the answer too late.